# getting empty array in mongoose by using mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var mongooseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    empId: Number,
    empName: String,
    empId: Number
});
var Model = mongoose.model("employee", mongooseSchema);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/company");
Model.find(employeeDetails)

function employeeDetails(error, data) {
    if (error == null) {
        console.log(data);
    } else {
        console.log(error)
    }
    mongoose.disconnect();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Model = mongoose.model("Model", mongooseSchema, "Employees");
```

Comment: Do you mean this is the solution? Consider adding a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.

Comment: Welcome Jani. For solutions add some commentary above your example code to explain that your  suggested example code is the recommended structure. If other lines of the op's code should also be changed to work with the structure you suggest, then either show how they must be changed also, or state that they should operate fine with your suggestion. Explanations help the op and other readers.